# How to change Chrome language with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I would like to run Cypress with the terminal using the Command Line.
However the Chrome I'm running run is set to English.
Which is really odd because when I run the test with the Cypress runner it's run in the native language of my Chrome.

How can I do to set the correct language ?
What I tried so far is :

`cypress run --browser chrome -e --LANG=fr-FR`

What can I do to set the Chrome in the needed language?

Comment: So, I had a look and it appear that the chrome that is launch take the language of my OS :/

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Ola, yes thanks :)